# C++ OpenCV hand gesture recognition

Tags: c++, opencv, detection, gesture-recognition

Im new at OpenCV, im trying to make a C/C#/C++ (I will use any of them) application that uses hand gestures to control your computer with a normal webcam/kinect camera (normal webcam preferred). Ive seen people do it on youtube before, but I want to do it myself.

Something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQxiFaZbOfA

Please any help or tutorials so I can make this application.
I know its a lot to ask for, but please give me some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should take a look at color tracking and feature detection

[Here is a great tutorial about color tracking](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSeFrPrqZ2A)

[And a tutorial about feature detection](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjxWpKCQqJc)

Good luck for your project !

Answer (score 2):

there's some information you can start with by using Orientation Histograms for Hand gesture recognition [here](http://www.merl.com/papers/docs/TR94-03.pdf).

I'm also looking for some ready-to-use API solution, not a research solution like this.